# what is compiler feedback based optimization? is it available with arm gcc compiler?

Tags: gcc, arm, neon

what is compiler feedback(not linker feedback) based optimization? How to get this feedback file for arm gcc compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [chapter](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) of the GCC documentation dedicated to [optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (and also the section about ARM in GCC: [ARM options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html#ARM-Options))

You can use:

- [link-time optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) (LTO) by compiling *and linking* with `-flto` in addition of other optimization flags (so `make CC='gcc -flto -O2'`): the linking phase also do optimizations (so the compiler is linking files containing not only object code, but also intermediate [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) internal compiler representation)
- [profile-guided optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization) (PGO, with `-fprofile-generate`, `-fprofile-use`, `-fauto-profile` etc...): you first generate code with profiling instructions, you run some representative benchmarks to get profiling information, and you compile a second time using these profiling information.

<sup>You could mix both approaches and give a lot of other optimization flags. Be sure to be consistent with them.</sup>

On x86 & x86-64 (and ARM natively) you might also use `-mtune=native` and there are lots of other `-mtune` possibilities.

Some people call profile-based optimization compiler feedback optimization (because dynamic runtime profile information is given back into the compiler). I prefer the "profile-guided optimization" term. See also [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1673844/841108).